# How can i execute this command from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have this command which runs on the prompt:

`echo "python setHeater.py" | at 16:30`

how can i execute that from a Python program?

In my program i create a date, and concat that to a string, something like this

```
newtime = createnewtime()
commandToExecute = 'echo "python setHeater.py" | at ' + newtime 
#and then here the code to actually run the command in the command environment
```

Comment: paste your entire python script?  Are you using datetime to make your time (with a custom function of createnewtime())?  Also, what's the end goal?  Really just to print this to stdout?  Are you trying to actually "echo" this via sys/os modules?

Comment: Why run a python script from a python script? If you really want to execute that command then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python. But I'd recommend importing what's in setHeater.py into your current script and do the scheduling in Python. Otherwise you have unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Jonathan i am not trying to run a python script from my python script, i am trying to schedule the next run for my script

Comment: @Nascent: i'm running a script (can't post it yet, it's full of loose ends like this :-)) and in that script, i will schedule the next run time for that script (using the `at` program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OS library:

```
import os

newtime = createnewtime()
command = 'echo "python setHeater.py" | at ' + newtime
os.system(command)
```

Although if you are trying to execute this command you don't need to use "echo". Simply:

```
import os

newtime = createnewtime()
command = "python setHeater.py | at " + newtime
os.system(command)
```

Comment: without the echo, the command is executed AND scheduled?

Comment: This actually works, did'nt I read somewhere that it is 'better' not to use os.system()?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could execute a command using `subprocess` library like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

newtime = createnewtime()
p1 = Popen(["echo ", "'python setHeater.py'"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["at", newtime ], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Instead of running setHeater.py explicitly, use `import sys` and then `sys.argv[0]` - this means the script will still work if you change the name.

Comment: When i run this, i get this result:

Comment: `/usr/bin/python /home/setHeater.py
echo "/usr/bin/python /home/setHeater.py" | at 17:01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/setHeater.py", line 6, in <module>
    returnCode = call(commandToExecute)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Source is then:
`from subprocess import call`
`newtime = "17:01"`
`commandToExecute = 'echo "/usr/bin/python /home/setHeater.py" | at ' + newtime`
`print(commandToExecute)`
`returnCode = call(commandToExecute)`
`print(returnCode)`

Comment: Hm... can't seem to get the formatting in a comment, i use backticks around every line...

Comment: When you changed source did it work?

Comment: when i use your example but change the commandToExecute line to `+ '17.30'` at the end (so hardcode the time) it gives me the same errors. Reading the errors, I'm not sure which file or direcory it can not find?

Comment: When i change the commandtoExecute to `echo "Michel" > michel.txt` i get the same error.... Can i use the `|` and `>` symbols in the `call` command?

Comment: what if you try this: commandToExecute = "python setHeater.py | at " + newtime?

Comment: Same errors, can the PIPE symbol do any damage?

Comment: Yep possible I've edited code please try that.

Comment: Still no luck. I've replaced the newtime with a hardcoded string `File "setHeater.py", line 4, in <module>
    p1 = Popen(["echo ", "'python setHeater.py'"], stdout=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`